# Postgresql pivot row data without aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot, pivot-table

I have this table:

```
create table student
(
    key serial primary key,
    id int, 
    type_name text,
    updated_by text,
    updated date, 
    text_data text,
    int_data int
);
```

Sample table and data is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2a9a46a46ded161455fe68135ecd15e)

A student `id` may have multiple rows(marks) for same subject. I would need to pivot all marks of each students for each subject.

I'm trying to pivot data with below query

```
select 
    id,
    max(updated_by) as updated_by,
    max(updated) as updated,
    max(case when type_name='Name' then text_data end) as "Name",
    max(case when type_name='Math' then int_data end) as "Math",
    max(case when type_name='English' then int_data end) as "English",
    max(case when type_name='Social' then int_data end) as "Social",
    max(case when type_name='Science' then int_data end) as "Science"
from
    stud 
group by 
    id
```

But this is not giving all marks for `id` 1 and in `Math` subject has marks 8 and 5. since i used max function in my query, i'm getting single value.

But it seems without aggregate function we can't do group_by.

Is there way in Postgresql to pivot data without aggregate functions to get below expected output

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need as another aggregation, namely **`STRING_AGG()`** along with **`FILTER`** clause such as

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(text_data) AS "Name",
       STRING_AGG ( int_data::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY key ) FILTER (WHERE type_name='Math') AS "Math",
       STRING_AGG ( int_data::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY key ) FILTER (WHERE type_name='English') AS "English",
       STRING_AGG ( int_data::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY key ) FILTER (WHERE type_name='Social') AS "Social",
       STRING_AGG ( int_data::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY key ) FILTER (WHERE type_name='Science') AS "Science"
  FROM stud 
 GROUP BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b750ec7f2b0ebeb2494eef421b9ac50e)</kbd>